# how to use QP=Quadratic Programming in svm

Tags: matlab, svm, quadratic-programming

I am using svm for anomaly detection as follow

```
svmStruct = svmtrain(tr,label,'kernel_function','rbf','ShowPlot',true);
ok1 = svmclassify(svmStruct,test1,'ShowPlot',true);
```

default separating hyperplane method is SMO but I want to use QP i.e. Quadratic programming . how to use it in above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `'method'` property of `svmtrain` to `'QP'` explained in the [documentation of svmtrain](https://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/svmtrain.html)

```
svmStruct = svmtrain(tr,label,'kernel_function','rbf','ShowPlot',true,'method','QP');
```

Section of the documentation:

> 'QP' — Quadratic programming (requires an Optimization Toolbox™ license). The classifier is a 2-norm soft-margin support vector machine. Give quadratic programming options with the options name-value pair, and create options with optimset.

svmtrain will be removed in future Matlab releases so if your planning to use it in the future consider using [fitcsvm](https://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitcsvm.html).